# radio with values from picklist

Tags: visualforce, picklist, radio-button, selectradio

I have a picklist with values and I need to display them not as dropdown but as radio-buttons, is there an easy was to do it? Maybe even without a custom controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like no easy way, so my ordinary solution is:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public InterviewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { }

    private List<SelectOption> getSelectOptions(String fieldName) {
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = 
            Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPickListValues();

        List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry entry: pick_list_values) {
            options.add(new selectOption(entry.getLabel(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getValues() {
        return getSelectOptions('qty_of_of_facilities_serviced__c');
    }
}
```

VisualForce:

```
<apex:selectRadio layout='pageDirection' value='{!account.my_field_picklist__c}'>
    <apex:selectOptions value='{!values}'></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think , there is way in salesforce to achieve this. may be some hack in javascript to change the element from picklist to radio.. but again for Javascript you need a custom VF page.. and if there is custom vf page , I would like to go with the apex , vf rather than looking for javascript hack.